# The rank of elliptic curves of the form $y^2=x^3+ax$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am looking for references of the following two questions:

1) 
For with class of primes the rank of the elliptic curves $y^2=x^3+px$ is exactly $0,1$ or $2$. It was quite easy to show that the rank is $0$ for $p\equiv 7$ or $11 \pmod {16}$. But what about other primes? How "good" we know the tank these days?

2) Is there any method (which an undergrad student could understand) for determining generators of the group $E(\mathbb Q)$ when $rank(E(\mathbb Q))>0$ and $E$ is given by $y^2=x^3+ax$?

Answer (score 2):

In Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" the classical results on the Mordell-Weil rank of these curves are summarised in chapter $X$, section $6$, which is called "The Curve $E: Y^2=X^3+DX$" for fourth-power free integers $D$. Proposition $6.2$ gives us the formula, for $D=p$ prime, 
$$
{\rm rank} \; E(\mathbb{Q})+\dim_2 Ш (E/\mathbb{Q})[2]=\begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } p\equiv 7,11 \bmod 16 \\ 1  \text{ if } p\equiv 3,5,13,15 \bmod 16 \\
2 \text{ if } p\equiv 1,9 \bmod 16 
\end{cases}
$$
The left-hand side is called the Selmer rank. From this we can derive that for $p\equiv 7,11 \bmod 16$ the rank of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is $0$, and $Ш (E/\mathbb{Q})[2]=0$. For $p\equiv 5\bmod 8$ the rank is at most $1$; it would follow from the Birch-Swinnerton Dyer conjecture that it has rank exactly $1$ for *all* primes $p\equiv 5\bmod 8$, but this is of course open. So taking together all remarks in this section of Silverman's book you will obtain an answer, what was known until, say, $1992$, about primes $p$ with rank $0$, $1$, or $2$. I think the experts can tell you what the status is today. There are of course several papers on the web, which you might want to look at, e.g., [Goto's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1148393036) from $2001$, and the references, and his [PhD thesis](http://www.ma.noda.tus.ac.jp/u/tg/files/thesis.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course I know this book, but I did not noticed that section. I will go through it. Can you also answer my second question?

Comment: The general approach is to use the method of $n$-descent, for one or more suitable integers $n$. This is not a typical undergraduate subject, but Silverman book is an excellent reference for understanding.